# PyInstaller-Generated .exe closes Immediately When Running Google Palm-2 program

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pyinstaller

I wrote a short example of a Python program that sends a prompt to the Google Palm-2 model and receives a reply from the model. My program runs correctly when I run it in the command console with the ".py" extension. However, after I created an ".exe" file using Pyinstaller, and ran the ".exe" file, the command window closed immediately without running the program. Has anyone else experienced the same problem? I spend hours looking into the Pyinstaller analyzer log and at the run time error message and could not find a solution.

```
import google.generativeai as palm

# Configure the PaLM API
palm.configure(api_key='my-api-key')
input_text = "What is the capital of France?"
# Get the model's response with the given input text
response = palm.generate_text(
    model='models/text-bison-001',
    prompt=input_text,
)
# Get the corrected text as a string
response = response.result
# Print the reply
print("Result:")
print(response)
print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this GitHub issue may have information regarding your issue:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5774

Try adding the following:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('grpc')
```

Comment: Lardsonian, thank you so much!!! Your suggestion worked. I wonder how you found this solution. To save readers from having to go to GitHub, I've added the complete solution below. Create a file named hook-grpc.py. Include the following content in the file: 
`from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_
data_files datas = collect_data_files('grpc')`

paste the hook-grpc.py file in the following directory: 

`C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks –`

Answer (score 1):

Try having a look at this part of the Documentation: https://www.pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

I would try adding `--debug=all` when creating the EXE to get any information on what went wrong.

Comment: I already looked at it before I posted my question and could no find anything wrong.  However I managed to capture the first error message during the execution before the command window closed. It is: 
E1019 22:09:05.149000000  1760 src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl_utils.cc:578] ASSERTION FAILED: pem_root_certs != nullptr

Comment: Because the program is so short, I was hoping that someone would try this program using their own Palm2 Key. The key is free.

Comment: @Menachem That is not a realistic expectation for Stack Overflow, it is not a debugging service.

Comment: Thank you for your input. You are right that Stack Overflow is primarily a platform for sharing knowledge and helping each other learn. While it is not a dedicated debugging service, it's a great place to ask specific, well-formulated questions related to programming.

Comment: In the past, I've contributed solutions to platforms like Stack Overflow and similar forums. My contributions typically involve running code posted by others and troubleshooting issues. 
In certain instances, it can be challenging to pinpoint whether the problem lies with my setup or with the Pyinstaller program itself. That's why I believe that having someone else run my straightforward code could prove invaluable in identifying the root cause and subsequently sharing a solution to benefit the community.